# Delay display of an object is moving items on different z-indexes

Tags: html, css

I have a container div. Inside that I have 6 things. A banner div, an upperstrip div, a video div, a counter div and a bottom div. Inside the bottom div is a lowerstrip div.

When the delayed item displays it bumps the lowerstip div down the page by the amount the the counter is located. All of these divs except for the container have z-indexes called out in my CSS.

```
<div id="container" style="text-align: center;">
<div id="banner">
    <img src="banner.png" alt="banner" />
</div>
<div id="upperstrip">
    <p><h2 style="color:white; background-color: #0f2781;"> 
    Puzzle Registration </h2></p>
</div>
<div id="video">        
    <video controls autoplay>
    <source src="prsm_animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
    <div id="counter" data-delay="9" style="display:none; width: 100%">
    </br>
    <a href="http://www.xxxx.com">
    <img src="bluebar.jpg" alt="bluebar" /></a>
    </div>
</div>      
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="lowerstrip">
        <p><h4 style=" color: white; vertical-align:bottom; 
        background-color: #0f2781; text-transform: uppercase;"> 
        Enter your puzzle number in the blue bar above to 
        register for these 
        great prizes! </h4></p> 
    </div>  
 </div>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
}
#counter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 803px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}
#upperstrip {
    position: static;
    width: 850px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 40;
}
#lowerstrip {
    position: static;
    width: 850px;
    top: 400px;
    height: 19px;
    z-index: 60;
}
#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width:850px: height: 1300px;
    z-index: 80;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Here's a demo. Please explain what the "delayed item" is. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/63v2qkgu/1/

Comment: Static positioning ignores z-index. You probably want all your elements positioned absolutely.

Comment: The delayed item is just a jpg at the moment. It's a banner that will show up at the near the bottom of the video after about 9 seconds.

Comment: I've changed the static positioning to absolute.  Not sure why I had static there anyway.